# D3js - Force Layout. Selecting Specific Node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to select a specific node and do some animation on it.

This is how I try to select it:

```
var selectedToEnlarge = node.filter(function (d, i) {
        return d.name == selectedVal;
    });
```

This variable actually return an array containing my node. Please see attached image:
[image: Circle selection result]

The node returned is the one I need.

Now I try to animate it a bit, like this:

```
selectedToEnlarge.transition().duration(2000)
                .attr("stroke-width", 20)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
                .attr("r", 200)
                .ease('sine')
```

But nothing is happening. I am assuming it is something with selectors.

Any insight is appreaciated :)

Comment: It looks like you're selecting a `g` element, which doesn't have `stroke-width` or `r` attributes. You probably want to select a `circle` element.

Comment: This selectes a circle: var enlarge = d3.select("circle"); but not the one I need. How can I be more specific?

Comment: Can't tell you more without seeing the code. I don't know what circles there are and which one you want to select.